# Get relative path in Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, relative-path

I've got this app where I'm using an IHttpHandler to serve JSON data to my JavaScript method.

```
  var theUrl = location.href;
  var txtCity = '#<%= txtForSaleCity.ClientID %>';
  var hidCity = '#<%= hiddenForSaleCityID.ClientID %>';
  var theSource = '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/RegionsAutoComplete.axd")%>?PID=<%= hiddenBusinessProvince.value %>';
```

This works fine on my "localhost" webserver, but I've also got a staging server for my clients to use. `http://staging.infinitas.ws/ClientSite/`

The problem that I'm having is that when the app is hosted on the staging server, the `theSource` is mapped incorrectly (contains /ClientSite/).  I could do something like a `String.Replace` but I'm looking for a more elegant way of achieving this.

Comment: Note, I'm **not** using MVC on this project so those helpers won't help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/RegionsAutoComplete.axd")
```